# Call Struts1 action from Struts2 application

Tags: struts2, struts1

We have 2 struts1 applications, earlier we have one call from one application to other.

In 1st application in config.xml we are calling 2nd application using below functionality,

```
    <forward name="inquiry" path="/inquiryaccount.do?prefix=/inquiry&amp;page=/inquiryconnect.do" redirect="false" />

    <action path="/inquiryaccount" type="org.apache.struts.actions.SwitchAction" />
```

And we have inquiryconnect.do present in other application config.xml

Now we have migrated one application from struts1 to struts2. And in struts2 config.xml (struts.xml) but I didn't found any **SwitchAction** like class to call other struts1 action.

I have tried with below but not working.

```
<result type="redirectAction">
                <param name="inquiry">inquiryconnect.do</param>
                <param name="namespace">/inquiry</param>               </result>
```

It is giving me 404.

Could anyone guide me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own Question.

In Struts.xml, have a dynamic result such as:

```
<result name="success" type="redirect">${url}</result>
```

In the action:

```
private String url;

public String getUrl()
{
 return url;
}

public String execute()
{
     url = hostPath+"/appnametojump/actionclassname.do";         
     return "success";
}
```

By using above code now we can call Struts1 application from Struts2.